# Java SMTP Mail failure

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

We have automated regression tests , after which we would like to send auto generated mail.
WE are using simple java email jar , but when we run code we get below message-
Connected to host "smtp.office365.com", port: 587 , Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM

Can someone tell what do I need to do so that I will be able to send mail.

Thanks,
Nilesh

Comment: It sounds like your mail provider requires authentication.

Comment: Make sure you're calling the connect or send method that supplies a username and password.

Answer (score 0):

As it is stated [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_winother/client-was-not-authenticated-to-send-anonymous/d405bcb0-f40c-42fa-b1b2-477597100123):

> This indicates that you are connecting to the SMTP client submission endpoint (smtp.office365.com), which can't be used for direct send. For direct send, use the MX endpoint for your Office 365 tenant, which ends with "mail.protection.outlook.com." So, please let your admin check the MX record. Moreover, please check if the SMTP port is 25/TLS.